# How to ask a specific question to differentiate two types of average

Tags: statistics

Imagine I have a a school with three classes: class 1 has 1 student, class 2 has 2 students, class 3 has 4 students

I am interested in the "average class size"

If i were to report this based on the number of students in each professor's class i would get the following: 
$$
\frac{1 + 2 + 4}{3} = 2.3333
$$

If i were to report this based on the student's reports of their own class size i would get the following: 
$$
\frac{1 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4}{7} = 3
$$
Both of these seem to be plausible answers to the question "what is the average class size". My question is if i wanted one particular account of the average class size how would i define the questions so that they would differentiate these two accounts? Is that possible?

Comment: This is related to *size biasing* (see Section 2 [here](http://bcf.usc.edu/~larry/papers/pdf/csb.pdf)). If the original distribution is $p(1)=p(2)=p(4)=\frac{1}{3}$, then its mean is $2.33$. The second distribution is the size-biasing of the first distribution, and it has $p(1)=\frac{1}{7}$, $p(2)=\frac{2}{7}$, and $p(4)=\frac{4}{7}$, and its mean is $3$ as you calculated

Comment: It matters if you ask all the students, or just a sample (like only one student per class)

Comment: Ok, skimming size biasing section of that paper makes sense. The latter calculation is not the average. However what is the mean of that figure? Imagine i have survey data in which respondents were asked: how many students are in your class with you? How do I accurately describe the mean of that variable if "average class size" is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking if you have a sample partitioning of the universe $U$ into
$$
U = P_1 \uplus P_2 \uplus \ldots \uplus P_n,
$$
where $n_i = |P_i|$ and $N = \sum_{k=1}^n n_i$, the average partition size should be determined by 
$$
\frac{N}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n n_k \quad \text{or} \quad 
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^n n_k^2 = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n n_k^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n n_i}.
$$
I don't see a valid reason to count each student's piece as an independent observation of the average, after all you have $n$ groups in the partition, and no matter how many people you ask what the size of each group is, it will not change the sizes of the groups.